# Access template class parameter in default lambda argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a simple universal pool. The template class takes a parameter in the constructor that is a factory function to instantiate objects in the pool as needed.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    std::function <T*()> factory_;
    Foo(std::function<T*()> factory): factory_(factory) {}
};
```

This compiles fine, but I wanted to make a default argument for the constructor using lambda:

```
Foo(std::function<T*()> factory = [](){return new T();} ): factory_(factory) {}
```

This does not compile - it says that T is unknown. Is there a way to make lambda expressions aware of class template parameters? I tried using `typedef`, but to no avail.

Comment: [it works perfectly for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b076b37262cd8e), which might indicate a bug in vs2013...

Comment: @Massa I guess it is a bug then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should work as proposed, however you might have hit a bug in VC++ (it's not exactly C++11 ready yet).

As a workaround, you might try to replace your lambda by a private static method instead.

```
template <typename T>
class LIFOPool
{
    std::function <T*()> factory_;
    //...details irrelevant

    static T* DefaultMake() { return new T{}; }
public:
    LIFOPool(std::function<T*()> factory = DefaultMake) : factory_(factory) {}
    //...details irrelevant
};
```

Comment: Alternatively, I would try sprinkling `typename` before the `T`'s in the OP's code :D

Comment: @Massa `T` isn't a dependent type...  The problem is, I'd guess, that the right hand side of a default argument assignment is evaluated in the calling context, and in that context `T` is not known.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, unfortunately. Lambdas are much cleaner in such scenarios, though.