# VC++ 2013 errors while using member initializer list with lambda as a member

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am having a hard time understanding the origin of these compilation errors.

Following code compiles without any problems on gcc-4.9.3 and clang-3.8 but is failing on VS 2013.

```
class Sample
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        explicit Sample(T& in) : 
         x(in), 
         lamb( [](Sample& ss)
         {                                                          
           std::cout << "This works !!\n" << static_cast<const T&> (ss.get()) << std::endl;
         }){}

        const int get() const { return x; }
    private:
        int x;
        std::function<void(Sample&)> lamb;
};

int main()
{
    int z = 10;
    Sample a(z);
    return 0;
}
```

I end up with following errors:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'T'
```

The MSDN explaination for these errors did not help much. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OAkFvu1qV9ESP7Pc) [without](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LUNHOZZie6GL93E9) [any problems](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/THuTNjFlnhTnokAB), indeed.

Comment: Oops... :) :) I updated the question with a snippet which indeed compiles well on gcc and clang. Still errors out on VS 2013.

Comment: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ uses VS and it shows the actual error message which makes it clear that the lambda cannot use the constructor's template argument T (the line with the static cast)  As to whether it should, I would go with clang and gcc but that's a personal opinion without a reason.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384256/access-template-class-parameter-in-default-lambda-argument) is perhaps similar to my issue...Is this a VS 2013 compiler bug then?

Comment: I'd rry vs2015 and see if MS fixed this already. If not, check Clang. If that works, there is a high chance of MS failing to do the right thing.

Comment: It does **not** compile in VS2015 either (with `error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'T'`) on line with `static_cast`

Comment: [VS 2015 Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2731448)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that visual studio doesn't pass info about template type T into lambda. I've passed class variable to lambda to gather needed type info. Something like this works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Sample
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        explicit Sample(T& in) : 
         x(in), 
         lamb( [this](Sample& ss)
         {                                                          
           std::cout << "This works !!\n" << static_cast<decltype(x)> (ss.get()) << std::endl;
         }){}

        const int get() const { return x; }
    private:
        int x;
        std::function<void(Sample&)> lamb;
};

int main()
{
    int z = 10;
    Sample a(z);
    return 0;
}
```